# shared_ptr's std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong comparing with raw pointer

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, atomic, compare-and-swap

Is it possible in shared_ptr's `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` to compare with raw pointer?

Like so:

```
    struct Chunk{
       // atomics
       std::shared_ptr<Chunk> prev;
       std::shared_ptr<Chunk> next;
    };

    // chunk is guaranteed to stay alive while this operation
    void remove_chunk(Chunk* chunk){
        std::shared_ptr<Chunk> prev = std::atomic_load(&chunk->prev);
        std::shared_ptr<Chunk> next = std::atomic_load(&chunk->next);

        // Can I do this?
        std::shared_ptr<Chunk> self{chunk};
        std::atomic_compare_exchange_strong(&prev, &self, next);

        ...
    };
```

I thought about this, because http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp says that compared only raw pointers. But is this required by standart, or just optimisation side-effect?

The question is only about `atomic_compare_exchange_strong` correctness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost certainly, this is wrong. In `remove_chunk(Chunk* chunk)`, `chunk` is probably just identifying the chunk to remove. In `std::shared_ptr<Chunk> self{chunk};`, you imply that you were the owner of `chunk`, and `self` becomes the new owner.

Comment: `chunk` is guaranteed to stay alive while this operation.

Comment: @tower120: Well, no, as `self` forcefully takes ownership, transfers it to `prev`, which then goes out of scope and deletes the chunk. Your statement indicates that you really should have written `remove_chunk(Chunk& chunk)` and then the compiler would have caught the bug.

Comment: damn you're right. There where global lock before, now I switched to per chunk lock...